# How to hide a column when creating a table using Angular 2's *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a table that takes my object and displays information to the user like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th style="background-color:#009bbb;color:white;width:10%">app Id</th>
            <th style="background-color:#009bbb;color:white">Int Id</th>
            <th style="background-color:#009bbb;color:white">Name</th>               
          </tr>

          <tr *ngFor="let provider of listOfProviders; let i = index" (click)="setSelectedProvider(provider)" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.href]="'#collapse' + i" class="panel-heading">
           <td>{{provider.appId}}</td>
           <td>{{provider.intId}}</td>
           <td>{{provider.name}}</td>
           <div [attr.id]="'collapse' + i" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" style="margin-left: -550%;margin-top:30%">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <table id='resourceTable' class="table table-striped" style="width:70%">
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <th style="background-color:#009bbb;color:white">Uri</th>
                    <th style="background-color:#009bbb;color:white;width:30%">Status</th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr *ngFor="let item of provider.resources">
                    <td>{{item.uri}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.status}}</td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
```

So, the way the table works is that the user will see three columns in the table, and earlier in the form I ask them to click on the row they want to see.  In my object, I have one appId, one intId, and one name per entry, but they could have up to 30 'resources', so I wanted to display them in a separate table.  What happens is that when they click on the row they want to see, a second table below the information will appear, and everything about having the data works great.  However, when there are only three columns originally, a fourth will appear with an 'empty' heading when the user clicks the row.  Is there a way to stop *ngFor from displaying an empty heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is just the placement of your `*ngFor`. If you move it up to the `<tbody>` tag, it will only render the `<th>` for rows with data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7avxt.

Comment: yeah, just had to move the *ngFor up a layer :)